# Using Maven site deploy for http transfer to a Nginx docker container

Tags: java, docker, nginx, documentation-generation, maven-site-plugin

I have a Maven project that I am generating documentation for and I am using the Maven Site Plugin to do so. I would like to run mvn site:site to generate it and then mvn site:deploy to upload it onto a running Nginx docker container. As Nginx natively only supports Http requests, I would like to know if this is even possible. The mvn site:site will be generate to my project folder locally and I am trying to run site:deploy to upload that onto an Nginx container. Also note that I am trying to use Wagon as well to enable Http with WebDAV.

Comment: `site:deploy` uses scp.

Comment: Forgot to mention that am trying to use Wagon to change it to HTTP (via WebDAV)

Comment: Did you solve this issue? How did you enable webdav support on nginx?